# JQuery ajax- current URL doesn't work

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, spring-boot

I've looked at thousands of articles about my problem, but i didn't found a solution.
Here we go.
When I'm using ajax with url specified as the url of view when i want to use a script it doesn't work. I'm using POST type and receiving data in spring controller. When I change url to something else and do the same in requestmapping value, everything works fine. What possibly causing this problem ? AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
type : "POST",
url : "/login2",
data :
    {x: x}
,
success : function() {
    alert('fine');
},

error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert(xhr.status+status+error);
}
});
```

SPRING:

```
     @Controller
      @RequestMapping
       public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login() {

        return "login";
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/login2",method =RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void login2(@RequestParam(value="x[]") String x[]){
    System.out.println(x[1]);
}


}
```

Code above works fine but
When url is "/login" for whole class and methods are specified the same it doesn't work ..

Can You help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter for login2 is array of string. Whereas you are sending object from ajax.

Comment: I know, x is an array. For login2 its work, when i change url for login it doesn;t

Answer (score 0):

try reading the values from Request body instead of request param.

```
login2(@RequestBody String x[])
```

Comment: try this return "login.html";

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem is that this is my page declared as login apge in Spring Security ?